# Where would one ask QA/QC questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a specific forum for quality control and quality assurance?  Or are those more properly covered in specific forums that use QA/QC protocols?  (Such as https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions.)  If a person had questions about NQA-1 or other non-software or computer related QA/QC, is there a good place to ask those?

Comment: It seems we don't have such a site as SQA is about software quality assurance so doesn't cover NQA-1. You could propose something on area51. Or you could suggest on SQA's meta that they broaden their scope since they are still in beta.

Comment: Depending the scope of QA/QC, you could ask on some sites: QC (or more like Review) for coding, [codereview.se]. I think other sites might cover those. I don't know of any site for Mechanical Engineers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: Since the question isn't actually asking about software at all, that's clearly extremely wrong.

Comment: @Gnat - Nathan Tuggy is right, this is about QA that is NOT software related.

Answer (score 1):

If it is related to Mechanical or Quality Engineering,  you may probably ask on [Engineering StackExchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com).

From [on-topic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions on Engineering Stack Exchange are usually well-received when they:
>
> - Identify a specific engineering problem
> - Require expert engineering knowledge to solve
> - Include any relevant drawings, images or references that may be necessary to understand the problem
> - Excite or challenge experienced professionals in the field

It has following tags which may be relevant to your question:

- [Mechanical Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags/mechanical-engineering/info)
- [Quality Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality-engineering)
- [Product Testing](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-testing)
- [Measurements](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags/measurements/info)